# Force SSL + www + Subdirectory with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following domains:

```
http://example.net    -> https://www.example.com/
http://example.org    -> https://www.example.com/
http://example.com    -> https://www.example.com/
http://theexample.com -> https://www.example.com/
```

I'm lost looking for a way to be able to force redirect all these domains to a single domain that uses **www** and **https** including all subdirectories.
The main domain is **example.com** and I need to redirect it including subdirectories like:

```
http://example.net/blog     -> https://www.example.com/blog
http://www.example.org/blog -> https://www.example.com/blog
https://example.com/blog    -> https://www.example.com/blog
http://theexample.com/blog  -> https://www.example.com/blog
```

**https://www** and the domain **example.com** is mandatory all subdirectories.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Rather than checking for the hostnames to redirect, you could instead just check that the scheme + hostname is not the canonical and then redirect to it. So, if the request is *not* for `https://www.example.com/...` then redirect (copying the URL-path).

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

The above states... for all requests where HTTPS is either `off` or not `www.example.com` then redirect to `https://www.example.com/<URL-path>`. `$1` is a backreference to the capturing subgroup in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. the URL-path). Any query string is also copied through by default.

The `=` prefix on the *CondPattern* makes this an exact string match, not a regex. And the `!` prefix negates the regex (ie. does *not* match).